# Trouble adding to a variable in a for loop [Python]

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, turtle-graphics

I'm reading a book called "Math Adventures With Python" where it teaches you cool math experiments through the turtle module. The book offers a challenge where you are to make a spiral out of squares where the squares get larger every time. [It's supposed to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnG2Q.jpg) I've been trying to increase the size of each side with an increasing variable inside a for loop but I get this error: **local variable 'x' referenced before assignment**

I have tried adding the variable inside a different loop and creating the variable inside the function.

```
from turtle import *

x = 100

def square():
    for i in range(4):
        right(90)
        forward(x)
        x += 5


for m in range(100):
    square()
    right(6)
```

Comment: try making x a global variable by adding `global x` at the start of your function

Comment: Are you really supposed to increment `x` inside the loop? It won't be a square, because each side will be a different length.

Comment: On a side note - `import *` is a bad practice, instead do `import turtle as tr` and then `tr.right`, `tr.forward` etc.

Comment: you should neither use `global` or use `import *`, those are _very_ bad practice

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't increment `x` inside the loop, as that will make each side a different length, so it won't be a square.

You should make `x` a parameter to the function, and increment it in the loop that calls it.

```
def square(side_len):
    for i in range(4):
        right(90)
        forward(side_len)

for x in range(100, 600, 5):
    square(x):
    right(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to not get local variable 'x' referenced before assignment, you need to make x a global variable. The way to do this is:

```
def square():
    global x 
    for i in range(4):
        right(90)
        forward(x)
        x += 5
```

Comment: Global variables are bad practice - the solution is in including the argument into the function definition such as `def square(x)` instead of `def square()`